# Set Prompted Excel Spreadsheet to new Workbook Object

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to assign a new excel worksheet that is being prompt to open as a new Workbook Object. I'm trying the below code, however it's not working

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveGeneratedReport()

   Dim newWbReport As Workbook
   Dim MonthlyComplianceReport As Workbook

   Set MonthlyComplianceReport = SelectWorkbook

End Sub

Private Function SelectWorkbook() As Workbook

   Dim strFileToOpen As String
   strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Compliancy Report for export", _
                   FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

   If strFileToOpen <> False Then  '<---- Error Ocuring here
      Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFileToOpen
   End If

End Function
```

I'm receiving the

> "Type Mismatch"

error, however if I just run the function `SelectWorkbook()` it works fine and opens the document.

My end goal here is to open the document and then assign it to a Workbook object. Any suggestions to fix this error?

**EDIT:**

I should clarify my question here too... How can I assign this newly opened Workbook via the prompt to a Workbook object so that the rest of my code can work with it?

**EDIT 2:**

This seems to be working really well

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveGeneratedReport()

   Dim newWbReport As Workbook
   Dim MonthlyComplianceReport As Workbook

   Set MonthlyComplianceReport = SelectWorkbook


   Debug.Print MonthlyComplianceReport.Name

End Sub

Private Function SelectWorkbook() As Workbook

   Dim strFileToOpen As String
   strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Compliancy Report for export", _
                   FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

   If strFileToOpen <> "" Then
      On Error GoTo ErrHandle
      Set SelectWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFileToOpen)
   End If

   Exit Function
ErrHandle:
   If Err.Number <> 1004 Then
      MsgBox "Error " & Str(Err.Number) & Chr(13) & _
             "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & _
             Err.Description
   End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetOpenFilename` returns a `String` so it wont ever be true or false. Test for an empty string instead:

```
If strFileToOpen <> "" Then
```

Edit:

To set the workbook object change it to this:

```
Private Function SelectWorkbook() As Workbook
   Dim strFileToOpen As String
   strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Compliancy Report for export", _
                   FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

   If strFileToOpen <> "" Then
      Set SelectWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFileToOpen)
   End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, that answered half my question. Sorry I put an edit in to further clarify my question

Comment: I just found the MSDN page where you found your example, and it's wrong lol

Comment: I approved your edit, I wasn't looking at the big picture.

Comment: Thanks for your help, everything is working as intended now! :)